# Shortcode to delete post from front end

Tags: shortcode, trash

I'm trying to create a short code to delete post that user publish from the front end of my site.

I've tried the short-code below but I keep getting the error "The link you followed has expired." Kindly see image screenshot below.

```
  //Shortcode to delete post
    function delete_my_posts() {
        ob_start();

            $url = get_bloginfo('url');
     if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)){
       echo '<a class="delete-post" rel=”nofollow” href="';
       echo wp_nonce_url("$url/wp-admin/post.php?action=trash&post=$id", 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
       echo '">Delete post</a>';
     }

       return ob_get_clean();    
    }
    add_shortcode( 'delete_me', 'delete_my_posts' );
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3iuJ.jpg

Can someone kindly advise on this error?

Thanks

Comment: `$post` and `$id` are not defined in your code. And you should better off use [`get_delete_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_delete_post_link/).

Answer (score 1):

Following is the reformatted version of your code. `get_delete_post_link()` is used for fetching delete post URL so that we dont have to worry about nonce stuff. `global $post` is kept to avoid PHP notice which is currently there in your code. Please check it.

```
function wpso_delete_my_posts() {
    global $post;
    ob_start();
    if ( current_user_can('delete_posts', $post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a class="delete-post" rel="nofollow" href="' . esc_url( get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ) . '">Delete Post</a>';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'delete_me', 'wpso_delete_my_posts' );
```

Comment: Great! It works fine. How would I go about adding a redirect after the post is deleted? I tried using the wp_redirect function to redirect to another page after deletion, but instead, when I click the delete post link it redirects before deleting. I placed the wp_redirect function both at the bottom and at the top of the return statement for the shortcode but it didn't work. Any ideas as to where I can place the function?